# I am Usign flutter_facebook_auth but It says No implementation found for method login on channel app.meedu/flutter_facebook_auth

Tags: flutter, dart

Itssays  IMPORTANT: When you install this plugin you need to configure the plugin on Android before run the project again . If you don't do it you will have a No implementation found error because the facebook SDK on Android throws an Exception when the configuration is not defined yet and this locks the other plugins in your project. If you don't need the plugin yet please remove or comment it. I didnot get how to configure it

Answer (score -1):

> seems you needs to do this
> https://facebook.meedu.app/docs/4.x.x/android

Kindly refer to this
https://facebook.meedu.app/

Comment: i got configured my app

Comment: Still same resp